# inputstream closed without reason

Tags: java, exception, servlets, inputstream

i have inputstream for a zip file , the zip file has 1 XLSX File and the others are zips file, i passed the inputstream to read the XLSX file, the process is done without any problem, but i want to use the inputstream again to read the photos.zip which is included in the root zip , here it triggers a stream closed exception . here is my code.

```
for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
                    ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(item.get()));

                    ZipEntry entry = null;
                    while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                        if (entry.getName().contains(excel)) {
                            readExcelContent = new ReadExcelContent();
                            readExcelContent.read(zipStream);

                        } else if (entry.getName().contains(photoZip)) {
                            fillContentImage = new FillContentImage();
                            fillContentImage.read(zipStream, contextPath);
                        } else if ((entry.getName().contains(videoZip))) {
                            fillContentVideo = new FillContentVideo();
                            fillContentVideo.read(zipStream, contextPath);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and here is the ReadExcel class

```
    public ArrayList<FillContent> read(InputStream stream) {
    XSSFWorkbook wb;
    try {
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
            FillContent objFillContent = new FillContent();
            XSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);
            XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
            objFillContent.setOrder(i + 1);
            objFillContent.setContentName(cell.toString());
            cell = row.getCell(1);
            objFillContent.setServiceid((int) (Double.parseDouble(cell
                    .toString())));
            cell = row.getCell(2);
            objFillContent.setContentDiscreption(cell.toString());
            cell = row.getCell(3);
            objFillContent.setVideoType(cell.toString());
            fillContentExcel.add(objFillContent);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fillContentExcel;
}
```

Comment: I suspect Apache POI might be closing your stream internally.

Comment: what should i do then ?

Comment: Take a look at the source to verify - it's only my suspicion (I haven't verified myself). If it's confirmed, you'd probably have to open a new stream.

Comment: i thought that there is a better way to do that